# What is the best way to batch insert (less than 100 entities) using DB Contex(EF)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, batch-insert

I'm writing a WebApi solution and the architecture is done in a way that only controller layer can commit (save changes in the db) using the unit of work. I needed to do a batch insert (less than 100 entities). I tried to go with the following

```
        foreach (var req in Reqs)
        {
            await unitOfWork.GetService<IReqService>().AddNewReq(req);
            try
            {
                await unitOfWork.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
        }
```

But it fails if one of the entities fails to be committed, I understood that the issue is once I have one bad entity linked to the db, every time I will try to commit, I will be committing everything not committed yet which includes the new entity I'm trying to add AND the ones that failed to be committed. Meaning nothing will be added.

I was reading around on how to solve this and read something about detaching the entities that fails but I'm not sure if it would be the way to do it with such an architecture.

I think it's relevant to post the Commit code so:

```
    public async Task Commit()
    {
        if (_tenantDatabase != null)
            await _tenantDatabase.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Comment: The purpose of a unit of work is to treat operations against a context as a single unit. if you have operations that can succeed or fail independently then these should be bounded by separate units of work.

Comment: @StevePy Alright, I think it makes sense, my architecture isn't built in a way to help me do such things. I just wanted to make sure that I'm not missing something out or so!